Load Joomla! 5.2 framework from external file
I need to instantiate the Joomla! 5.2 framework from an external file, but I can't get it to work.
In Joomla! 3, I created a method to be used by AJAX calls to return module content. First, the Joomla! framework was instantiated, as shown here: Load Joomla 3.x Framework and Modules in external PHP file. After that, the module was rendered and returned.
However, in Joomla! 5.2, I can't instantiate the framework. Initially, the language was not set. I forced the language to load, but now I'm encountering an issue with the Template Component.
Does anyone have any advice?
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication;
use Joomla\Session\SessionInterface;

if (!defined('JPATH_BASE')) {
    define('JPATH_BASE', '/home/myinstallation'); // Path to Joomla
}


require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';

try {
    // DI-Container
    $container = Factory::getContainer();

    // Register alias for session
    if (!$container->has(SessionInterface::class)) {
        $container->alias(SessionInterface::class, 'session.web.site');
    }

    // Load the application
    $app = $container->get(SiteApplication::class);
    Factory::$application = $app;

    // start session
    $session = $app->getSession();
    if (!$session->isActive()) {
        $session->start();
    }

    // Get the menu
    $input = $app->input; 
    $menu = $app->getMenu();

    // Get menu default item ID
    $defaultMenuItem = $menu->getDefault();
    if ($defaultMenuItem !== null) {
        $menu->setActive($defaultMenuItem->id); // ID des Standard-Menüpunkts setzen
    } else {
        echo "Can't find default menu item." . PHP_EOL;
    }

    // Instantiate language manually
    $language = new Joomla\CMS\Language\Language('en-EN', JPATH_BASE);

    // Load language files
    $loaded = $language->load('joomla', JPATH_BASE, 'en-EN');
    if (!$loaded) {
        throw new \RuntimeException("Can't load language files.");
    }

    // Set language manually
    Factory::$application->loadLanguage($language);

    // Debug output
    echo 'Language loaded successfully: ' . $language->getTag() . PHP_EOL;

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    die('Error starting Joomla: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

